# How to install Tortoise client in Linux machine

Tags: linux, tortoise-svn

How can I download and install the TortoiseSVN client on a Linux machine?

I am using PuTTY to access the machine, so please give the installation steps using shell commands.

Comment: [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) is a Windows-only software. You can't install it on Linux.

Comment: i want to install Subversion client on remote box which dont have UI. so i have to install using putty. please suggest me.   Thanks

Answer (score 7):

**RabbitVCS** is TortoiseSVN analogue in Linux, it can be run from terminal and integrates to Nautilus, GEdit, etc.:

http://rabbitvcs.org/

Answer (score 3):

You can't install TortoiseSVN on a Linux machine, as TortoiseSVN is Windows only. You've a few alternatives:

- Use the command-line Subversion utilities over PuTTY to work with your working copy.

  To check if you have them installed, try running `which svn` on the system; if you get something along the lines of `no svn in (blahblahblah)`, you need to install Subversion. The command you need is probably one of `sudo yum install svn` or `sudo apt-get install svn`.

  Once you have this, you'll use more commands to work with your working copy. Search for "svn commands" with your favourite search engine for hints.
- Find a Linux based graphical user interface, and set up X11 forwarding, so windows you open on the remote machine appear on the local machine. The University of Minnesota have produced a [brief guide on configuring X forwarding with PuTTY](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html); it looks good but I've not tried following it myself.
- Set up a Samba share so you can access files on the remote machine directly using Windows, at which point you can use TortoiseSVN on your local Windows machine. There's a [guide to setting up Samba shares](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202605) on the Ubuntu forums, and the steps will be pretty similar on other flavours of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distribution, you have to install the 'subversion' package, not going with tortoisesvn. The plugins for the different IDEs will present the GUI for you, if you need one. For simple checkout/commit you can use the command line tool.

Comment: He says he's connecting to the linux box with putty, so he probably won't have a GUI.

Comment: true, although if you want to install a graphical tool on a box, you expect to have a graphical environment. But most probably you have a point!

Answer (score -2):

Just type on the command Prompt : `sudo apt-get install subversion`

Comment: This covers only dpkg/apt based distros (mostly Debian, Ubuntu) and won't work on Redhat, Arch Linux, Gentoo, Suse or Slackware